# Botrule appear longer than both Toprule and Midrule

Tags: tables

Please I am trying to prepare a manuscript using a journal template. I have the code below:

## Full Text

```
    \documentclass{cta-author}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[]{changes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[]{changes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[hbt!]
\processtable{Heading\label{tab8}}
{\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth}}\toprule
Heading1  &Heading 2  &  Heading3 \\
\midrule
000000000000000
000000000000000000
00000000000 &
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
  & 00000000000000000000000000  \\
\botrule
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}{}
\end{table*}
%vfill\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

On display, the botrule gets far longer than the top and midrule. I am not sure if the botrule is adjustable or something. I had expected all to be equal. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full (but minimal) self containd example instead of sniplets. Here we do not know your documentclass or preamble, both things that might be important. So please provide an example others can copy and test as is. And where does `\processtable` come from?

Comment: \processtable is preferred by the journal instead of \caption. I also saw that they prefer \botrule instead of the usual \bottomrule. The example above is a working example.

Comment: note `\begin{table*}[hbt!]` seems very wrong, `table*` does not support `h` or `b` so this is the same as `[t]`  so the only affect is to stop `p`, if you allowed `p` you presumably wouldn't get the warning "Text page 8 contains only floats." so wouldn't need the silence package to stop being warned about that.

Comment: Thanks, David. I got that warning earlier, but not as a result of this table in question that I am trying to create.

Comment: @ibiangalex sure but we can only comment on the code shown, you haven't provided a test file that produces the actual issue you are asking about. But presumably the floats that did generate the warning had a similar option (you would never get that warning normally as unless you disable the usual float positioning it can not happen)

Comment: This is not a complete example, and where do one get that class? it is not a known class.

Comment: @daleif the class is authored by the journal IET software

Comment: Then provide a link to the class

Comment: Where is defined `\botrule`?

Comment: @daleif the class link please https://drive.google.com/open?id=17eezb2_A9f_NYX6TPABnyc1CP_pwKBcF

Comment: as well as the class link you should provide a test file that shows the problem (and does not load dozens of packages not needed for the issue) so people can trace  what is happening and test answers.

Comment: @David, please find the test example.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1se6JyAnNh-er5S5Y6be8OG-2mvZ4mx7m

Comment: Again, please update the question, don't post links.

Comment: Right. Updated.

Comment: Dear all, It appears the definition of the dimensions which relies on the \textwidth is not effective. I have been playing around with different percentages of the textwidth and getting different outcomes. In fact, I changed the botrule to bottom rule and continued playing around with different sizes of the textwidth until I got it all equal. I am new to Latex. I believe there is a better way of resolving this than just guessing like I did. The table finally looked as I expected but the solution is not a good one I think.

Answer (score 3):

The class implements its own version of `\toprule` and `\midrule` plus `\botrule`. When you load `booktabs` its version of `\toprule` and `\midrule` are now used and they are defined differently.

Remove `booktabs` and the rule have the same length